# Volume reducing resistor in speaker lines

Tags: resistors

I recently ordered a small amp from ebay, a LVPIN LP-A6, 4-8ohm, 20w. The speakers available to use with it are from a stereo which says 4 ohms under the wire tabs. Not sure if that means each or both are 4 ohms.
This gets extremely loud for the small apartment I'm in. Not even an eighth of a turn and it's way too loud. Would a resistor in the speaker lines be a good way to handle this, and what value would you recommend given the stats above? Dropping the level to 1/8th would be good. (Not a shared ground).

Comment: (sqrt(8)−1)⋅4ohm = 7.3ohm

Comment: Which input port are you using for your input signal?

Comment: I tried the same thing with my 50W guitar amp: Put a series resistor to waste some of the output power and guess what? Sound became dull. Less trebles, less dynamics...

Answer (score 9):

Adding resistors in series with the speakers as you suggest would work, but is not a good idea, for two reasons:

- Additional distortion: the impedance of the speaker is not exactly 4Ω over the entire range of frequencies, whereas the resistor will have a constant resistance, whatever the frequency. So it means that, depending on the frequency, the speaker will see a different RMS voltage across it (the frequency response will be less homogeneous).
- Wasted power: dropping the level to 1/8th means that the resistors will dissipate most of the power from the amp, and this is just wasted as heat (and you'll also need bigger, more expensive resistors).

It would make more sense to attenuate the *input* to the amp, using another pot, or just a fixed resistor divider (actually two, one per channel).

Here is what you can do, for each channel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnGUBI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust R2 to get the level you need (the lower the value, the lower the volume). Here, with a 4.7k resistor, you get about 1/3 the voltage, so it means 1/9 the power, and is pereceived as about half the loudness. If you put a 1.1k, you'll get 1/10 the voltage, so 1/100 the power, and it will be percieved as about 1/4 the loudness.

Comment: Given that speakers generally don't have perfectly uniform frequency response, I wouldn't think that the audio effects of series resistance would be all bad.  If the inductance of a coil causes impedance to increase with frequency while output volume decreases, series resistance would compensate in some measure by attenuating higher frequencies less than lower ones.

Comment: @supercat Well, as I see it, there are two options: either you don't care much about the distortion, and all is fine, indeed. Or you care (maybe too much), in which case you probably have multi way speakers with some embedded crossover. In this case, the effect of this resistor is much harder to predict than what you mentioned, but it has much more chance to make things worse than improving sound.

Comment: Whether a resistor would make things better or worse would depend upon the design of the loudspeaker.  If the speaker is designed well to be driven from a very-low-impedance source such as a typical modern amplifier, adding series resistance would be unlikely to help.  If it is designed to be driven from a higher-impedance source, such as an older tube amplifier, adding resistance may improve performance at the expense of power efficiency.

Comment: this is the correct way to do it. Putting dropper resistors in speaker wires is a terrible way to reduce volume. For one thing, loudspeakers have *very* nonlinear impedance versus frequency, although in practice it doesn't sound that bad. (Higher output impedance of the output transformer is one of the facts thought to give valve amps their characteristic "warm" sound.) But also you generate significant heat in the dropper resistor, and that's just silly. It is so easy to do it at the input.

Answer (score 0):

Using a voltage divider would reduce the power to the speaker, while avoiding most of the effects of the speaker's natural variable impedance.  For instance. using a 2 ohm resistor across the speaker's terminals, and a 4 ohm resistor in series would reduce the voltage to approximately 1/3 of the original, and hence reduce the power to 1/9 of what it was.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3HYFv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The power calculation is incorrect. The speaker will see a voltage source of V1/3 with a source resistance of 1.33 ohms. This means the voltage across the speaker will be (4/5.33)*(V1/3) giving the power in the speaker of approximately 1/16 of the original value.