# What wattage should the resistors or pots be in a car audio voltage divider?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, stereo

[image]

My new radio amplifies the output too much and my car stock amplifier is non-adjustable. The only solution (that I know) besides putting the stock stereo back in, is 4 voltage dividers. I'd like to cut the volume by at least 1/2 if not by 1/4 (stereo in lowest setting is too loud). 1 post says use 10k ohm then a 4.7k to ground, and then says 4 ohm and 2 ohm.

[Volume reducing resistor in speaker lines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278198/volume-reducing-resistor-in-speaker-lines)

However what wattage should those resistors be? My stereo claims 4 channels of 60 watts each, should each resistor or pot be 60 watts or greater?

The intent is to have them wired as in the post referenced in the link.

Any suggestions as to option in lowering the head unit's signal to the amp would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! If you are doing this on the signal side, all you need is two low power potentiometers or four fixed resistors. Please draw a block diagram to clarify what you have and how they are connected.

Comment: How are they connected now? From line level output or from speaker level output to amplifier input?

Comment: 4 and 2 ohms would be correct AFTER the amplifier - but very wasteful (and need resistors that can handle just about the full amplifier power) Use the schematic shown on the INPUT to the amplifier, then reduce R2 as needed.